# Declaration of global members inside a class in c++

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration, scopes

I am trying to program a microcontroller to move a motor and perform other functions with an encoder and some potentiometers. I want to use a library that sends pulses to the motor driver via a pulse width modulation signal, but as far as I understand the classes of this library rely on static variables, which I don't know how to access from my own class. This is a simplification of my header:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Teensystep.h>
#define startStop               2
#define stepPin                 3
#define dirPin                  4
#define channelA                5
#define channelB                6
#define enabPin                 7
#define dirSwitch               8
#define soundTrig               9
#define chipSelect              10
#define mosiSdi                 11
#define misoSdo                 12
#define clk                     13

#define led                     A3
#define potSpeed                A4
#define encoButton              A5
#define sensor                  A7

class Example{

public:  

        void moveMotor();

};
```

This would be my example.cpp, where I use motor and controller, which are global objects:

```
#include <example.h>

void Example::moveMotor(){

    ::motor.setTargetRel(1024);
    ::controller.move(::motor);
}
```

And here is my main.cpp file:

```
#include <example.h>

  Stepper motor(stepPin, dirPin);
  StepControl controller;
  Example exampleObject();

void setup(){

  pinMode(enabPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(channelA, INPUT);
  pinMode(channelB, INPUT);
  pinMode(startStop, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirSwitch, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(encoButton, INPUT);

};

void loop(){
   exampleObject.moveMotor();
};
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know where to look for a solution, any help is welcome. Thanks.

In the files presented above, I am creating a class called `Example`, which has only one function that depends on two objects, `Stepper` and `StepControl`. These two objects have to be declared globally, since they have static members. For that reason I am writing the function of my class calling global objects:

```
#include <example.h>

void Example::moveMotor(){

    ::motor.setTargetRel(1024);
    ::controller.move(::motor);
}
```

However, when I compile the program the compiler tells me that

```
'motor' has not been declared. The global scope has no 'motor'
```

How can I make a member of a class a global object?

I am writing the program on Visual Code for linux with an extension for physical computing called platformIO and the library that I'm using is called [TeensyStep](https://github.com/luni64/TeensyStep).

Comment: Unrelated: The block of `#define`s in the header looks a lot like you should consider making it an [`enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Can you explain to me why ```enum``` is better than ```#define``` in this case?

Comment: `#define` is a simple text substitution that happens before just about everything else. There are no sanity checks or smarter logic applied to the substitution. Anywhere `startStop` is found in the code it is replaced by `2`, no matter how stupid or insane the substitution is.If you accidentally reuse `startStop`, for example a function `void startStop()`, the results can be truly bizarre, the function earlier is seen by the compiler as `void 2()`, and the error messages are almost always misleading. `enum` is processed during compilation and gets checked more thoroughly before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is broken:

> These two objects have to be declared globally, since they have static members.

No. When a class has static members you actually do not need any object to access those members.

It is not clear where you have `Stepper` declared, but it seems you are missing the `#include` when you are trying to access its members. If `setTargetRel()` is a `static` method of `Stepper` then you call it eg like this:

```
 Stepper::setTargetRel(1024);
```

If `setTargetRel` is not a static method, then you'll need an instance to call it. Still you shouldn't make this instance a global variable, but either make it a member of `Example` or pass it as parameter to `Example::moveMotor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll try it as soon as possible. So, if I understand correctly, the member ```setTargetRel``` can be called with ```Stepper::setTargetRel()``` without creating a ```Stepper```object?

Comment: @AntonioCastles I dont know. If it is a static method then yes

Answer (score 0):

Add to `example.h`:
`extern Stepper motor;`

Add to `example.cpp`:
`Stepper motor(stepPin, dirPin);`

```
void Example::moveMotor() {
    motor.setTargetRel(1024); // remove :: before motor
```

Remove from `main.cpp`:
`Stepper motor(stepPin, dirPin);`

This should allow all files including `example.h` to use the global variable `motor` - but there's something wrong with the overall design.

If `Example` is responsible for setting the target and initializing the movement, why doesn't it own both the `Stepper` and `StepControl` instances and provide convenience functions to keep the actions together? Example:

```
class Example {
public:
  Example() : 
    motor(stepPin, dirPin),
    controller{}
  {}  

  void moveMotor(int target=1024) {
    motor.setTargetRel(target);
    controller.move(motor);
  }

private:
  Stepper motor;
  StepControl controller;
};
```